# Historical question about tangent lines to disjoint circles

Tags: ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

It is pretty well known that two disjoint circles have 4 different lines that are simultaneously tangent to both circles. There are constructions with ruler and compass available in many books, but I would like to know about the source of this problem and its solution.

I searched in Euclid's elements and didn't find it. I've seen this attributed to Apollonius, but if I understand correctly his original works are mostly lost.

Comment: Apollonius Treatise on conic sections is not lost. Most of it survives and is even available in English translation: https://www.stmarys-ca.edu/sites/default/files/attachments/files/Conic_Sections.pdf

Comment: But the problem you are asking is too simple for Apollonius (and for Euclid too), though it is a very special case of some problems considered by Apollonius.